# What does number in Cassandra database tables denote?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

When we create a new table in cassandra database it automatically creates a folder for it in data location. While creating folder it also attach alphanumeric number with it after hyphen(-). What does that number denote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a unique identifier(UUID). This helps avoid issues with Drop-Recreate operations where a newly created table has the same name as an old table. This way they will have unique folders so if a drop message gets lost or whatnot the old data won't get restored into the new table.